SymPy not simplifying the multiplication of a matrix with its conjugate
I'm trying to simplify the multiplication of a matrix with its conjugate in SymPy, but the simplification is not happening as expected. Here's my code:
import sympy as sp

# Define symbols
e = sp.Symbol('epsilon', real=True, domain=sp.Interval(0, 1, right_open=True))
i = sp.I
p = sp.Symbol('psi', real=True)

# Define the Jones matrix with additional assumption
J = sp.Matrix([
    [sp.sqrt(1 - e), -sp.sqrt(e) * sp.exp(i*p)],
    [sp.sqrt(e) * sp.exp(-i*p), sp.sqrt(1 - e)]
])

# Create the conjugate matrix
J_conj = sp.conjugate(J)

# Compute the Kronecker product
J_prod = sp.kronecker_product(J, J_conj)

I try to use sp.simplify(J_prod) but the J_prod still the same.

I want the J_prod to present in this form:
expected J_prod


Apparently, SymPy sometimes struggles with complex numbers.
I think this may help:
J_prod_simple = sp.re(J_prod) + i * sp.im(J_prod)

